# How to fix error "No query results for model [App\Posts]"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I am getting error `No query results for model [App\Posts].`, but model returns result correctly. I am trying to use `pusher` to emit event about new post.

```
$post = \App\Posts::find(1);
if($post) {
    event(new \App\Events\NewPost($post));
}
```

Event:

```
class NewPost implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $post;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('messages');
    }
    public function broadcastWith() {
        return [
            'id' => $this->post->id
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's basically whole code, event which I want to emit, and function in controller which only send this event.

Comment: ``find(0)`` wast just bad example, I will edit post. In original code i use other id, and database returns good result, but still I have this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. This error was beacuse $post was serialised by SerializesModels.

Changing `use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;` to:

`use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets;` helped.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment ID in database always start from `1` not zero, then a `Post` with id `0` will never exists. Then, Eloquent does not find a record with id `0`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, 0 was an example, bad example it's not from original code. In original code using var_dump I get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what you found with `SerializesModels` it is because the trait forces the event to expect it to be JSON or an Array. To sort this without removing that trait you can call `->toArray()` on your model.

Like so:

```
event(new NewPost($post->toArray()));
```

more is written [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections)